# Let's get critical: Apr 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](http://movies.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I only got 7 question to evaluate, whats this matter? http://movies.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval/history

Comment: @AnkitSharma If you skip any of the review items, you don't get them back.

Comment: @jokerdino I didn't skipped any. And i am even the first person to self-evaluate the site.

Comment: @AnkitSharma you might post that to meta.so to get help.

Comment: @DForck42 done http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174790/movies-and-tv-site-self-evaluation-review-queue-not-giving-10-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why didn't Terrence Howard play Jim Rhodes (Rhodey) in Iron Man 2?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10295/why-didnt-terrence-howard-play-jim-rhodes-rhodey-in-iron-man-2)

  **Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 16, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Which is the first parody film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9929/which-is-the-first-parody-film)

  **Net Score: 13** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Who is the daughter of John Spartan in Demolition Man?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10113/who-is-the-daughter-of-john-spartan-in-demolition-man)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [How could Carl run or jump when he is using apparatus for his walking?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10115/how-could-carl-run-or-jump-when-he-is-using-apparatus-for-his-walking)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Where is Lost Girl supposed to be based?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10221/where-is-lost-girl-supposed-to-be-based)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Anime where mecha is controlled by a boy playing an ocarina](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10138/help-with-identifying-mecha-anime-please)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 7)
- [Identify this film where a school girl's personal diary got so much attention](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10213/identify-this-film-where-a-school-girls-personal-diary-got-so-much-attention)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What ammo does the Jonah Hex's super weapon fire?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9829/what-ammo-does-the-jonah-hex-super-weapon-fire)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What was the last movie to have a souvenir program available at showings?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/what-was-the-last-movie-to-have-a-souvenir-program-available-at-showings)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What was the inspiration for the trampoline storyline in "Aerodynamics of Gender"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10056/what-was-the-inspiration-for-the-trampoline-storyline-in-aerodynamics-of-gender)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 1)

Answer (score 1):

average score: 7.2
average score from previous evaluation: 1